# Правильность записи

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>             Иногда нумерация дублируется вопросов.  
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

system("chcp 1251>nul");

int a,A,B,C,D,E;
//  const int    //Размер массива
a=5;
srand(time(NULL));   //Инициализация генератора случайных чисел

int nums[a];       // Создание массива
for (int a=1;a<=5;a++){
nums[a] =1+rand()%(31);
cout<< "\t Вопрос № -  "<<  nums[a] <<endl;
cout<<"\n";
}


A=nums[1];

B=nums[2];

C=nums[3];

D=nums[4];

E=nums[5];

if(A==B&&C&&D&&E){                              //  Не работает
A=32;
}
else{
A=nums[1];
}
if(B==C&&D&&E){
B=33;
}
else{
B=nums[2];
}
if(C==D&&E){
C=34;
}
else{
C=nums[3];
}
if(D==E){
D=35;
}
else{
D=nums[4];
}
cout<<"\n"<<"\t A="<< A<<endl;
cout<<"\n"<<"\t B="<< B<<endl;
cout<<"\n"<<"\t C="<< C<<endl;
cout<<"\n"<<"\t D="<< D<<endl;
cout<<"\n"<<"\t E="<< E<<endl;

cout<<"\n"<<"\t nums="<<nums[1] <<endl;
cout<<"\n"<<"\t nums="<<nums[2] <<endl;
cout<<"\n"<<"\t nums="<<nums[3] <<endl;
cout<<"\n"<<"\t nums="<<nums[4] <<endl;
cout<<"\n"<<"\t nums="<<nums[5] <<endl;


return 0;
}

Вопрос:После запуска генератора сл.чисел выводится одинаковые числа. Чтобы 
этого не происходило добавил проверку с оператором if. Однако при сравнении 
в 1-ом и 2-ом оператор не работает, почему не понимаю. Программа ошибок не 
находит.
```

Comment: Да запросто! :) Сначала сравнивается A и B, потом - И с C,D,E (по необходимости - сокращенные вычисления, если не переопределены операторы). Если общее выражение истинно - присвоить 32 переменной A.

Comment: Я написал, как это будет вычисляться в соответствии со стандартами С++, а не то, что кто-то подразумевает...

Comment: @entithat эм... Странный вопрос) а равно б а дальше все само по себе правда.

Comment: @pavel, я имел ввиду будут ли выражения сравниваться с А дальше или просто будут считаться как истина, теперь уже ясно :)

Comment: Ну, вы же это записали. Значит **запись** определённо возможна. Выражайтесь детальнее. Скомпилируется ли? Выполнится ли определённым образом?

Comment: @Harry, не понял, разве не должно сначала вычислиться логическое И переменных `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, а результат сравниться с `A`?

Comment: @maestro Нет. См. приоритеты операций. Приоритет сравнения выше приоритета &&.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение `A == B && C && D && E` с учётом приоритета операций (приоритет `==` выше чем приоритет `&&`, который в свою очередь выше чем приоритет `||`) и с учётом ассоциативности оператора `&&` (также как и у `||` — слева направо) будет эквивалентно следующему:

```
(((A == B) && C) && D) && E
```

Также здесь следует учесть что оператор `&&` (как и `||`) вычисляется по сокращённой схеме (short-circuit evaluation).

Для оператора `&&` это означает, что правый операнд вычисляется в том и только в том случае, если левый `true`.

Для оператора `||` это означает, что правый операнд вычисляется в том и только в том случае, если левый `false`.

Более того, левый операнд является *упорядоченным перед* правым операндом, т.е. все вычисления и побочные эффекты связанные с левым операндом выполняются до всех вычислений и побочных эффектов связанных с правым операндом.

С учётом написанного, порядок вычисления приведённого выше выражения следующий:

1. Если выражение `A == B` ложно, то дальнейшие вычисления не производятся, и выражение `A == B && C && D && E` ложно, иначе
2. если `C` ложно, то дальнейшие вычисления не производятся, и выражение`A == B && C && D && E` ложно, иначе
3. если `D` ложно, то дальнейшие вычисления не производятся, и выражение `A == B && C && D && E` ложно, иначе
4. если `E` ложно, то дальнейшие вычисления не производятся, и выражение `A == B && C && D && E` ложно, иначе
5. выражение `A == B && C && D && E` истинно.

---

В вашей программе есть несколько ошибок.

Во-первых, размер массива `nums` должен быть константным выражением, т.е. переменную `a` следует объявить с квалификатором `const`:

```
const int a = 5;
```

Во-вторых, массивы в C++ нумеруются с нуля. Первый элемент в массиве `nums` имеет индекс `0`, а последний элемент имеет индекс `4`. Попытка обращения к несуществующему пятому элементу массива — неопределённое поведение — так делать не нужно.

В-третьих, вы пытаетесь проверить, равна ли переменная `A` хотя бы одной из переменных `B`, `C`, `D` или `E`, используя следующее условие:

```
if (A == B && C && D && E)
```

и это не верно. В первой части ответа я написал как вычисляется это условие.

Чтобы добиться последовательного сравнения переменной `A` со всеми остальными переменными используйте *логическое или*, а именно бинарный оператор `||`:

```
if (A == B || A == C || A == D || A == E)
```

С учётом приоритета операторов приведённое выше выражение интерпретируется так:

```
if ( (A == B) || (A == C) || (A == D) || (A == E) )
```

а с учётом ассоциативности так:

```
if (    ( ( (A == B) || (A == C) ) || (A == D) ) || (A == E)    )
```

т.е. тело `if` выполнится в том и только в том случае, если `A` равно хотя бы одной из переменных `B`, `C`, `D` или `E`.

Comment: Эээ... вы не перепутали левый и правый операнды &&? *"Это означает, что левый операнд бинарного && вычисляется в том и только в том случае, если правый true."*

Comment: @Harry, да, вы правы, исправил.

Comment: Вопрос решен,моя  благодарность wololo